# Python - How to sort a dictionaries values that is a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

As the title suggests I'm looking for a way to sort all the values in a dictionary, where the dictionary's values are a list of lists. I have included an example snippet below:

```
hubs = {
    '9999': [['#IPaddress#', 'Manual', '1859', '2104201557', '2104201530'], ['#IPaddress#', 'Manual', 
             'ImAwake', 'NoCardTrx', 'NoCashTrx'], ['#IPaddress#', 'Manual', '7513', '2104201613', 
             '2104201613'], ['#IPaddress#', 'Manual', 'ImAwake', 'NoCardTrx', 'NoCashTrx'], 
             ['#IPaddress#', 'Manual', '1456', '2104201609', '2104201607']]
}
```

Is there a way to sort by the #IPaddress# which will be the first element of each list? Where IP address will be a string in the format XX.XX.XX.11 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are looking for somthing like this:

```
for lst2d in hubs.values():
    lst2d.sort(key=lambda lst: lst[0])
```

If you want numerical sort for real IP-addresses:

```
for lst2d in hubs.values():
    lst2d.sort(key=lambda lst: [int(x) for x in lst[0].split('.')])
```

which will sort the dict values which are nested lists by the first element of their sublists.

Comment: `lst2d.sort(key=lambda lst: lst[0].split('.'))`